# How to have ? after a url do something

Tags: html

Is there a way to have lets say http://yourlink.here?something=answer do something in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The part of a URL after the `?` (but before a `#`) is called the *query* or *query string*. It is included with the URL that is sent to the server, and changing it generally causes a new HTTP GET request to the server.

Usually the query is parsed by the server, and changes what data (HTML, JS, JSON, whatever) the server returns in the HTTP response. However, you *can* parse it client-side, using JavaScript. The [`window.location.search`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) property in JS will return the query portion as a string. You can then do things like use the [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to break the query string on `&` (in case there are multiple parameters), split each parameter on `=` (to separate name and value), and URL-decode the names and values (because there's a bunch of characters - such as `=`, `&`, or `#` - that aren't allowed to be present in literal form within a query name or value).

Note that, if you're trying to test for something there like a password check or the answer to a question, this is totally insecure. A malicious user could just read the JS source code on the page to figure out what value is expected, or edit the script to bypass the check entirely.